# Transfer money from German Postbank to USA

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, germany

I am moving back to USA and need to send my money back to my USA bank.
Tried to test send €100.   Money never received in USA.  Could someone please explain the correct information for these categories:

IBAN oder Kto:

BIC oder Bankcode:

Kreditinstitut:

Auftragswährung:

Betrag:

Zielwährung:

Verwendungszweck:

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer money to the US using IBAN. You'll need to use the SWIFT system. You should ask your US bank for directions on how to wire money to your account through SWIFT, and then with that go to your German bank and ask them to initiate the transfer.

Your German bank will be able to identify which piece of information goes into which field of the ones you've described (or maybe have a different, manual, process for SWIFT transfers).

Comment: IBAN is a way to identify an account, not a way to send money to it. For example Australian bank account numbers can be converted to IBANs but a European bank will still have to process it as an international transfer to Australia, not a SEPA transfer.

Comment: Regardless of the method, your German bank should be able to help you and perform the correct transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an international bank transfer but chances are this will be expensive.

If it's a non-trivial amount of money, I would go through a bank that's specifically offers efficient international transfers. I use wise.com (no advertising intended). I have set up two accounts with my "transfer bank": one in Euro with an address in Belgium (and an IBAN number) and one in US dollars with an address in the US.

Using Wise as an example: In your case you can transfer the money from Postbank to the Wise Euro account using IBAN. That's free and only takes a few seconds (as it should). You can than transfer between the two Wise accounts at a very low fee (0.4% the last time I did it) and then use an ACH transfer from the US$ Wise account to your US bank. Whether you have to pay for the ACH transfer and how long it will take depends on your US bank.